# Does outerHTML have the same XSS vulnerabilities as innerHTML?

Tags: security, xss, outerhtml

Our company's security scan seems to keep getting hung up on this outerHTML property in swfobject.js:

```
el.outerHTML = '<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"' + att + '>' + par + '</object>';
```

I'm familiar with the XSS vulnerabilities associated with innerHTML, but can you give me some examples of how outerHTML can be exploited in this case? I'm wondering if the scan is producing a false positive - I would think that the team behind swfobject would have addressed all XSS issues.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you understand how `innerHTML` and `outerHTML` works, you can answer the question for yourself:

- [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML) replaces all [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.childNodes) of the `el` node with the [*`NodeList`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/NodeList) that was parsed from the assigned string value.
- [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.outerHTML) replaces the node `el` *itself* with the *`NodeList`* that was parsed from the assigned string value.

An example: if `el` is the inner `div` in the following example:

```
<div id="outer"><div id="inner"> … </div></div>
```

Then setting `innerHTML` and `outerHTML` with `<b>foobar</b>` results in:

- `innerHTML`:

  ```
  <div id="outer"><div id="inner"><b>foobar</b></div></div>
  ```
- `outerHTML`:

  ```
  <div id="outer"><b>foobar</b></div>
  ```

So it doesn’t matter whether you use `innerHTML` or `outerHTML`. Both are vulnerable to XSS.